# How do I set PHP 8.0.11 error configuration to Development Machine since FastCGI displays HTTP Error 500.0 when configured

Tags: php, iis

I have set up PHP 8.0.11 in IIS 10 via PHP Manager. Everything works fine when error reporting is set to production but immediately it is configured in Development mode, phpinfo() shows HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error.
I have tried setting permissions for the PHP folder and the website. I have even configured error reporting manually but nothing seems to work. I need the development mode of the error reporting in order to fix upgrade issues. Any help will be much appreciated.

[image: Error Message From IIS]

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, i suggest you use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information. and you need to ensure the [VC++ runtime](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) is installed.

Comment: The detailed error information is attached with its error code. From research made so far, it seems the issue is with PHP 8 build itself. There error reporting is verbose and very detailed so I guess thats why it is causing issuws for FastCGI. I have managed to log the errors into a file but with no mode selected. It shows all the errors tho.

Comment: There will be detailed error messages of the Request Summary in FailedReqLog File.